# What are the relative differential forms of a family of (nodal) curves?

Tags: moduli-spaces, complex-geometry

What is the definition of relative differential forms of a family $\pi: X \to B$ of (nodal) curves, where $B$ is the base space.

Comment: hi quanting, welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: You can find a definition of relative differentials in almost any book on algebraic geometry.  Differential forms are just exterior powers of the sheaf of differentials.

Comment: hi shizhuo,it is nice to see you here --zhaoquanting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I learnt the following from the paper *On the relative de Rham sequence* ([MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=681850) [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2043718)) by Nick Buchdahl.  It is more general than the OP situation, but should easily specialise to it.

---

Let $f:X \to B$ be a smooth map between manifolds.  Then the sheaf $\Omega^1_f$ of germs of *relative 1-forms* on $X$ is defined by the following exact sequence
$$
f^*\Omega^1_B \to \Omega^1_X \to \Omega^1_f \to 0
$$

Then the relative differential $k$-forms are defined by
$$
\Omega^k_f = \Lambda^k \Omega^1_f
$$
as usual.  Differentiating along the fibres gives a differential $d_f: \Omega^k_f \to \Omega^{k+1}_f$.  and $(\Omega^\bullet_f, d_f)$ is called the *relative de Rham complex*.

When $f$ is a submersion, the relative de Rham complex gives a resolution
$$
0 \to f^{-1}\mathcal{E}_B \to \Omega^\bullet_f
$$
of the sheaf of functions of $X$ which are constant on the fibres.

Comment: Again JSTOR is selling something which is in free access: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-087-02/S0002-9939-1983-0681850-3/S0002-9939-1983-0681850-3.pdf

Comment: My apologies.  It was not my intention to peddle JSTOR's wares, I simply followed the "Article" link in MathSciNet.  Interesting that MathSciNet, owned by the AMS, should link to JSTOR instead of to its own journals...

Comment: Dear José, I was definitely not criticizing *you*! On the contrary, I am quite grateful to you for letting me discover this paper.